# ActiveMQ / JMS Message Handler Test

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

This is not totally on JMS Queue handler test. So, continue reading.

We have an architecture where spring channel listens to a queue from ActiveMQ. The listener of this queue will receive messages and has a static list of sub-listeners (identified by unique subjects). All the messages will have some parameters including the subject to which this message has to be delivered.

> SMSService will drop its messages to the activemq with a subject SEND_SMS. It will be listened either by some HTTP Service or SMPP Service. You can even design your own Listener and wire that as a spring component with the required "subject".

**Problem:**
There is a better chance that this internal subject might change. This doesn't even throw an explicit Runtime Exception when there are no listeners. Is there a way to test this message being actually received by the intended listener?

`

Comment: Problem statement is much to vague.

Answer (score 0):

As tim Bish siad, your problem statement is much too vague.

Have you tried to create your own ActivemMQ [interceptor](http://activemq.apache.org/interceptors.html) (I do not know if it could be usefull for your problem)